# Are class numbers of number fields with prime degree often $1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, heuristics

I have taken a look at the class number statistics of the L-functions and Modular Forms Database:

https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/stats, table "Distribution by class number".

It appears that for number fields of degrees $5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23$, the class number is disproportionately often equal to $1$ (in around 90 % of the fields as opposed to less than 50 % in most other degrees).

**Question: Is this a real phenomenon?** And if so, is anything known or conjectured, heuristically or theoretically, about it?

I am sure this observation about the table has been made before, but could not find any account of it.

Some thoughts:

- Some things are known for cyclic Galois extensions of prime relative degree. The fields in the database, however, are mostly non-Galois (e. g. 129 / 1,163,734 Galois fields in degree 7).
- The phenomenon could also be due to the way the fields are compiled (see https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/Completeness). The collection is only fairly extensive for degrees up to 7 and thins out to special families in higher degrees. Its enumeration by increasing discriminant, by Minkowski's / Bach's bound might favor fields with small class number.
- The phenomenon is less pronounced for the primes $2$ and $3$. For the case of $2$ this might be due to "roots of unity issues" which also appear in the Cohen-Lenstra heuristics for instance [Malle: https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~malle/download/clnums.pdf].
- While in general not much seems to be known about the map $Cl_K \to Cl_L$ for an extension of number fields $L/K$, the phenomenon might also be due to the non-existence of nontrivial subfields.

Comment: I can't speak for higher degrees, but in degree 2 we have that the density of fields, either real or imaginary quadratic, with class number 1 is equal to zero.

Comment: For imaginary quadratics, the roots of unity are not so relevant. You can remove the $2$-part of the class group and it will still be enormous on average. For real quadratics, it may be more of a factor. Roughly speaking, the more places at $\infty$, the smaller the class group. You need at least $2$ places at $\infty$ to have any chance of class number $1$, and it gets more probable the more places you have.

Comment: Your intuition about subfields is very relevant. If your field contains a smaller-degree field then the class group contains the class group of this lower-degree field (or almost all of it) and again it's hard to be trivial. More generally if the permutation representation of the Galois group associated to the field (i.e. the action on the conjugates of a generator) splits into low-dimensional irreducible representations, the class group will likely be larger, and if it does not, the class group will be smaller. Presumably this is the reason for the prime effect.

Comment: The predicted probability of obtaining class group $1$ for a given Galois group can be calculated from the Cohen-Martinet heuristics, at least if you remove the $p$-part of the class group for certain bad primes $p$. This should justify my vague statements above.

Comment: Wow, thank you!